# Best approach to send Scribe centralized logging output to elasticsearch

Tags: logging, elasticsearch, logstash, scribe

We're currently building a centralized logging platform for our multitude of services. The plan is to install a scribe client on every application server, which will forward the logs to a central scribe server.

The central scribe server is currently logging all the aggregated logs to disk. But now we want to index them on ElasticSearch for visualization.

My exact question is: What's the best (most robust, fault-tolerant, less computationally expensive & memory efficient) way to forward logs from a central scribe server's output to ElasticSearch for indexing?

Few ideas worth exploring:

1. Scribe Server -> File -> Logstash -> ElasticSearch
2. Scribe Server -> File -> [X] -> RabbitMQ -> Logstash -> ElasticSearch
3. Scribe Server -> File -> [Y] -> ElasticSearch
4. Scriber Server -> [Z] -> Elastic Search

Any good options for X, Y or Z? Which one's the best approach? Please suggest.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

According to me Z option is the best  approach. `ElasticSearch` is suitable for fault  tolerant system.  There is shard and replica definition for this mechanism. But you must consider about memory efficiency . The count of your indexed document will be increased by the time and it will require at least 2 times more storage space as there is only one shard and one replica definition in the default config file.

EDIT:
If you have already a central scribe server I assume that you have all log  messages on your central server. But all the options can be used for your app if you have no messaging structure for your central server. If you want to achieve your indexing asynchronously, you can use `RabbitMQ` or `Apache` solition. I think you can have a look at elastic search [performance considerations](http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/performance-considerations-elasticsearch-indexing/) for indexing. What is your indexing count per second ? Is it vital for your app? My other suggestion is `MongoDB`. If you don't insist on `ElasticSearch` , I could suggest you to search on `MongoDB`. You should check this [comparison.](http://db-engines.com/en/system/Elasticsearch%3BMongoDB)

Comment: Do you have any clues for what can be some possible candidates for the Z option?